# Prove that function $\mathbf{R}^3\to\mathbf{R}^3$ is injective

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Prove that $f:\mathbf{R}^3\longrightarrow \mathbf{R}^3:(x,y,z)\longmapsto (e^{2y}+e^{2z},e^{2x}-e^{2z},x-y)$ is injective.

Assume $f(x,y,z)=f(x',y',z')$, then this gives the system $\begin{cases}e^{2y}+e^{2z}=e^{2y'}+e^{2z'} \\ e^{2x}-e^{2z}=e^{2x'}-e^{2z'} \\ x-y=x'-y' \end{cases}$.

If I can conclude that $x=x'$, then it follows from (3) that $y=y'$ and from (2) that $z=z'$.

I tried adding (1) and (2) to obtain $e^{2x}+e^{2y}=e^{2x'}+e^{2y'}$, but I have no idea how to proceed. Could someone provide some help? I think there is just a method I don't see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add first two equation you get: $$e^{2x}+e^{2y}=e^{2x'}+e^{2y'}$$ so $$e^{2y}(e^{2(x-y)}+1)=e^{2y'}(e^{2(x'-y')}+1)$$

$$e^{2y}=e^{2y'}\implies y=y'\implies x=x'$$

Comment: This is really smart :) Thank you !